# Create a new file with a similar name in Emacs with Helm

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I always end up opening an eshell and executing find-file new-file-name, because helm always supplies me with candidates and a million options that don't look like the basic feature that I want: forcing the file to be called what I typed. For example, I want to great an org document called mto.org in a directory with another org file in it.

[image: Helm completes rather than letting me make a new file :(]

How can I force helm to create the file with the name I typed, so I can save 10 seconds by avoiding opening up eshell and adding a small, but (hopefully easily) avoidable disruption of my concentration?

Comment: If you have the external application `touch`, how about evaluating?:  `(start-process "touch-file" nil "touch" "moto.org")`  If you like that, then you can make it more elaborate to check the existence of a file with that name and if it exists then creating that name plus 1, 2, 3, etc. -- e.g., moto1.org, moto2.org, moto3.org.

Comment: is your helm package up-to-date? I think there was bug around this a while back.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can press `C-p` and select the line

```
[?] mto.org
```

and then just press `RET`. It will (ask you to) create the file with the name you typed.

Comment: Perfect. I should have guessed!

Comment: This is extremely nonobvious, so thank you very much!